# How to upgrade from magento 1.4.1.1 to 1.6?

Tags: magento-1.7

Can anyone tell me easy **step to upgrade** `magento from 1.4.1.1 to 1.6` ?

Answer (score 1):

Read this [answer](https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/safe-way-to-upgrade-1-7-0-2-to-1-9-3/td-p/65221)

> There are no easy ways and shortcuts for upgrade, unfortunately. If best practices are not followed, you'll have more work to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Getting backup of your site as well as database
2. copy latest magento and paste it to your root folder
3. delete var/cache folder
4. refresh page